# Css only applying on the header only and not on the footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs

I'm trying to make a blog website using ejs, but i'm noticing that the css styling is only applying to the header and the footer is getting excluded, I have saved my styles.css in a public folder and i have also saved my header and footer in partials folder and my home.ejs is saved in a separate folder called views(btw partials is a sub folder inside views)

This is my main file:

```
<%- include ("partials/header") -%>
    
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p><%=startingContent%></p>

<%- include ("partials/footer") -%>
```

This is my header file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Daily Journal</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/styles.css">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <p class="navbar-brand">DAILY JOURNAL</p>
      </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <!-- 6 -->
          <li id="home"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
          <li id="about"><a href="/about">ABOUT US</a></li>
          <li id="contact"><a href="/contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
```

This is my footer file:

```
</div>
<div class="footer-padding"></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Made with ❤️ by The App Brewery</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}
.navbar {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.navbar-nav  li a:hover {
    color: #1abc9c !important;
}

.footer-padding {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.footer p {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: What does your css code look like?

Comment: please provide the styles you are trying to apply and if possible please provide the screenshot.

Comment: also head tag does not mean <header> tag just so you know and there is also a <footer> tag and any html goes inside the <body> tag not the <head> so you should bring your nav inside the body tag

Comment: You're missing a closing tag (`</head>`) after you link your CSS file. (`<body>` and `<head>` should be siblings in the tree.) [Validating your html](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) is a great way to catch stuff like this.  You can View Source in your browser and paste it in to the validator directly.